# One SelectedItem For Multiple Wpf Controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list box Bound  to XML data correctly , but i have multiple Tree Views inside this listbox which you can select item for every one of them!
**i want single item selecting from all of these tree views.** which every one of those are inside an unique expander.
if you look at my xml data ,consider i have 2 groups inside xml , i can select item for both of those groups in listbox which now they are different treeviews in my ui , and i want single item selecting for all this listbox items.

```
 <ListBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMenuValue,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items,Source={StaticResource XmlSourceMenu}}">
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type revoxml:Group}">
                        <Expander Header="{Binding Title}">
                            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}">
                                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0">
                                            <fa:ImageAwesome Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Icon="{Binding Icon}" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            </TreeView>
                        </Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type revoxml:SubMenu}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0">
                            <fa:ImageAwesome Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Icon="{Binding Icon}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.Resources>
            </ListBox>
```

for easier understanding data for this listbox comming from xml file like this :

```
<MainMenu>
  <Group Title="title">
    <SubMenu  Icon="Inbox" Title="inbox" Tag="38"/>
    <SubMenu  Icon="CommentingOutline" Title="New Message" Tag="37"/>
    <SubMenu  Icon="Tachometer" Title="Archive" Tag="39"/>
    <Menu  Icon="CartArrowDown" Title="purchases" >
      <SubMenu  Icon="CartArrowDown" Title="new" Tag="26"/>
      <SubMenu  Icon="CartPlus" Title="list" Tag="28"/>
    </Menu>
  </Group>

  <SubMenu  Icon="InfoCircle" Title="info"  Tag="6000" />
  <SubMenu  Icon="Close" Title="close" Tag="0"/>
</MainMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should solve it ! but you need to implement your own selected item, or you could change groupboxes to expander and items control to tree view to match your code

```
 <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="HoverStackPanelStyle">

            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

<ScrollViewer>
                <HeaderedItemsControl Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items,Source={StaticResource XmlSourceMenu}}">
                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type revoxml:SubMenu}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0" Style="{StaticResource HoverStackPanelStyle}">
                                <fa:ImageAwesome Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Icon="{Binding Icon}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="{StaticResource nazanin}" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type revoxml:Menu}" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}">
                            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Title}" Margin="0 5">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}">
                                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type revoxml:SubMenu}">
                                            <StackPanel Name="StackPanel"  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0" Style="{StaticResource HoverStackPanelStyle}">
                                                <fa:ImageAwesome Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Icon="{Binding Icon}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="{StaticResource nazanin}" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </GroupBox>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                </HeaderedItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```